# Adobe Muse contact us widget

Tags: javascript, php, css, adobe, muse

I have designed the whole website using adobe muse but now I'm stuck on the contact us widget that Muse provides by default. I am getting the following error,

'Form PHP script is missing from the web server or PHP is not configured correctly on the web hosting server.'

I even add the to- email id in the widget  but still the same error. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You must upload the website to a host which supports PHP using FTP